# When I am trying to run the code in rubymine it is showing SDK error. I configured the SDK GEM but still it is showing the same error

Tags: ruby, rubymine

This is the error I am getting:

```
Rails server launcher '/Users/skallamadi/github1/itildesk/vendor/gems/will_filter/test/dummy/bin/rails' was not found in a project
```

[image: Rails server launcher '/Users/skallamadi/github1/itildesk/vendor/gems/will_filter/test/dummy/bin/rails' was not found in a project]

Comment: Which RubyMine and Ruby + Rails version do you use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing some code that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*